# Click on DrawerLayout cause Click on Main layout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have Activity with DrawerLayout, I implements the Click ClickListener. The problem is when the DrawerLayer is open and user click on empty area on the darwerlayout, OnClick called as if he clicked the object behind it in the main layout. 
I checked the Id comes to onclick, and its the object behind the drawer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
       android.view.View.OnClickListener{
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         findViewById(R.id.resetThekir).setOnClickListener(this);
         // when User Clicks on the drawer that's already opened and above the image 
         //it calls the Onclick as if he clicks on the Image.
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.addThkir:
        case R.id.currentThkirTxt:
        case R.id.thkirCount:
     }
}
```

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/resetThkir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/reset"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:entries="@array/menuitems"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? preventing that? or?

Comment: I want when user clicks on the drawer not to send me the object behind the drawer as if it was clicked. Example I have a image in the main frame,and text on the Drawer, when user clicks on the text it sends me that users clicks the image

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท just because a class implements the OnClickListener doesn't mean it's actually listening for click events.

Comment: How are you registering the listener?

Comment: findViewById(R.id.img).setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Post your XML please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `break` after each case:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.addThkir: addThkir() break;
        case R.id.currentThkirTxt: currentThikTxt() break;
        case R.id.thkirCount: thkirCount() break;
     }
```

Comment: this is not the problem. I meant not to add break due to business rewuirments. The id return by v.getId() is the image where I clicked on the drawer not the image